# Does Yodlee IAV destroy the id/password for the bank after verification is complete?

Tags: yodlee

I am trying to understand if Instant Account Verification API deletes or removes the user id and password for the bank after the verification is complete. I did not find that [documented in the API](http://developer.yodlee.com/Instant_Account_Verification(IAV)_API/IAV_Services_Guide/API_References) that are published on the site.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example that shows the call(s) involved in the scenario you have described?  Also, are you using the SOAP or REST API?

Answer (score 0):

IAV APIs does not delete or removes the user credentials on it's own. You need to call the [removeItem](http://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/removeItem) API which will remove the user credential and data.